# Getting the sum of values in same column in SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

My database is the list of product a company sold in a particular date and hour. What I need to do is to get the amount of products sold in a particular date and hour. I am quite new to SQL so please help.

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT SELL_DATE, SELL_HOUR, SUM(PRICE), FROM dbo.SOLD_ITEMS WHERE SELL_DATE > '2014-04-20'    AND SELL_DATE < '2014-04-26' AND SELL_HOUR = '9'
```

Comment: This is not how to ask a question. Explain what you're trying to achieve, what is actually happening, and what the difference is. Also, post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: okay. I will next time. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SELL_DATE, SELL_HOUR, SUM(PRICE), COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.SOLD_ITEMS 
GROUP BY SELL_DATE, SELL_HOUR;
```

Comment: wow. thanks! :D I did not include SELL_DATE in GROUP BY so I kept having an error. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Functions like SUM() are known as *aggregate* functions because they combine data from a column in some way.  When you use an aggregate function, you must also supply information about *which* values you are aggregating.

You do this with **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT SELL_DATE, SELL_HOUR, SUM(PRICE)
FROM dbo.SOLD_ITEMS 
WHERE SELL_DATE > '2014-04-20'
AND SELL_DATE < '2014-04-26' 
AND SELL_HOUR = '9'
GROUP BY SELL_DATE, SELL_HOUR
```